# Search files by specific time e.g. changed in the last 14 days

Tags: files, find, date, search

I am using Nextcloud and since the "retention" app is still not working on v20 I try to code an autodelete script for myself.

The problem is, when I upload files to the Nextcloud share the original creation date of the file is kept. Only the "change" and the "access" times are changed by the upload, when I look at "stat file.txt" for example.

I want the script to automatically delete all files which are uploaded more than two weeks ago from the current date/time independent of the original creation date of the file.

Any hints how I can search or list files with the criterion from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with `mtime`/`ctime`/`atime` for time of modification, metadata change or access and `+14` for two weeks.

```
find <path> -type f -ctime +14 -delete
```

(I suggest testing this first with `-print` instead of `-delete` to make sure it works correctly.)